# Scrapy repeating rows

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape through this site https://www.tahko.com/fi/menovinkit/?ql=tapahtumat.
In particular, I'm trying to scrape through the 3 tables on the site.

I've managed this with

```
tables = response.xpath('//*[@class="table table-stripefd"]')
```

Then I'd like to get each of the rows for the table, which I did with

```
rows = tables.xpath('//tr')
```

The problem here is, that after scraping and printing out some of the data I noticed that there are multiple entries for some rows.
For example, the event "Tahko vuorijuoksu" shows up on the website once, but in my scraped data I have 3 instances of it.

Could anyone point out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the selector like this:

```
rows = tables.xpath('//tr')
```

It will select every `tr` element in it self or descendent axis, unbounded by the parent element. So it will return all the 207 `tr` elements, for each of the 3 `table` elements.

To get only the `tr` elements childs of each table you can use it like this:

```
rows = tables.xpath('.//tr') # notice the .
```

Usually is more intuitive to write it like this:

```
for table in tables:
    rows = table.xpath('tr')
```

*This is only a suggestion though, the previous solution works just fine.*

Comment: Ah, figured it would be a pretty simple error.
Maybe one day I can actually understand xpath