# Return just first line values of a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping fighter stats from http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters, but when I iterate over the table with scrapy its returns just first tr values:

Tom Aaron       --  155 lbs.    --      5   3   0

What I'm doing wrong?

```
import scrapy


class FightersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fighter_spider"

    # urls
    start_urls = ['http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters']


    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('teste')

        # access fighter info in a row
        fighter = response.xpath("//table//tr")
        
        for info in fighter:
            yield {
                'first_name': info.xpath('//td/a/text()').get(),
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is how you are calling the descendant-or-self (`//`) axis on the whole document instead of in the context of the **current** node (`.//`).

Instead of

```
'first_name': info.xpath('//td/a/text()').get()
```

Use:

```
'first_name': info.xpath('.//td/a/text()').get() # Notice the .
```

It's very similar to an issue I answered today:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64306258/11326319

Comment: Happy to hear Matheus. Since the problem is solved, please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark.